# RxAndroid - fix Activity Leak?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, rx-java, rx-android

I've distilled things down to the Activity shown below with the associated build.config and activity_main.xml.

The problem is LeakCanary is reporting a leak of the Activity if you press BACK before the counter completes, whereas letting it run to the end doesn't.

I've an idea what's going on. I know there must be an anonymous inner class created in the Activity by the Observer which survives the onPause() call because if you watch the console you can see it continuing the count. I know I've unsubscribed at this point, but the thread in the process is still running as an inner class of the Activity, which is the hallmark of a leak. This isn't just an artificial corner case for me either, in my real app the count is supposed to continue after an orientation change, so I persist what's necessary in a retained fragment and pick up the count accordingly, with the same leak. I just didn't need to show it here to simplify the example.

MainAcivity.java:

```
package com.otamate.rxactivityleaker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Observable<Long> mObservable;
    private Subscriber<Long> mSubscriber;

    public TextView mTextView;
    public final static int MAX_PROGRESS = 10;
    public final static int EMIT_DELAY_MS = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LeakCanary.install(getApplication());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mSubscriber = createSubscriber();
        mObservable = createObservable();

        mObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(mSubscriber);
    }

    private Observable createObservable() {
        return Observable.create (
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<Long>() {

                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> sub) {
                    for (long i = 1; i < MAX_PROGRESS + 1; i++) {

                        Log.d("Observable", "Progress: " + i);

                        sub.onNext(i);
                        SystemClock.sleep(EMIT_DELAY_MS);
                    }
                    sub.onCompleted();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private Subscriber createSubscriber() {
        return new Subscriber<Long>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(Long val) {
                Log.d("Subscriber", "Loop " + val);

                mTextView.setText("Progress: " + val);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d("Subscriber", "Completed");

                mTextView.setText("Done!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("Subscriber", "Error: " + e);

                mTextView.setText("Error!");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mSubscriber != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onPause() Unsubscribed");

            mSubscriber.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.otamate.rxactivityleaker.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Idle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.otamate.rxactivityleaker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it could be leaking.

Comment: LeakCanary does! I suppose it could be a false positive. Try and run it as presented - it's just the blank template wizard from Android Studio with the changes mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.create` makes it [easy for you to shoot yourself in the foot](http://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/).

Your problem is here:

```
private Observable createObservable() {
    return Observable.create (
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<Long>() {

            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> sub) {
                for (long i = 1; i < MAX_PROGRESS + 1; i++) {

                    Log.d("Observable", "Progress: " + i);

                    sub.onNext(i);
                    SystemClock.sleep(EMIT_DELAY_MS);
                }
                sub.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

When creating your Observable you are NOT checking if the `Subscriber` unsubscribed before calling `onNext/onCompleted`. You are also not handling back-pressure.

Check out [AbstractOnSubscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/AbstractOnSubscribe.html) it can help you create your `Observable` easier.

EDIT: `AbstractOnSubscribe` was removed in 1.1 but maybe [SyncOnSubscribe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/884e49b437c25fa44d2469a3a0388a756dc40d2d/src/main/java/rx/observables/SyncOnSubscribe.java) will work.

Comment: That sounded promising, so I wrapped the sub.x() calls with "if (!sub.isUnsubscribed())" but it made no difference. Is back pressure an issue here in such a simple test? And SyncOnSubscribe doesn't seem to be implemented in rxAndroid.

Comment: @CarlWhalley Back pressure should not be a problem here. Not canceling the job when unsubscribing is. Checking `!sub.isUnsubscribed()` does not cancel the loop maybe that is the problem? `SyncOnSubscribe` should be available in RxAndroid 1.1.0

Comment: I don't want to cancel the loop. I want the app to continue showing a progress bar when there is an orientation change which is picked up where it left off. I kept getting these leaks with that approach so posted this minimal version to illustrate it. I ultimately want to unsubscribe then resubscribe, but keep the job the Observable started going, which is not a simple counter but a task that could take 30+ seconds. This works with no leaks when I use an AsyncTask approach and also when I use an IntentService/BroadcastReceiver. I just need the same using RxAndroid without these leaks.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK You should be saving your subscription and unsubscribing from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Subscription subscription;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LeakCanary.install(getApplication()); 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mSubscriber = createSubscriber();
    mObservable = createObservable(); 

    subscription = mObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(mSubscriber);
}
```

Than in onPause()

```
@Override 
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 

    if (subscription != null) {

        subscription.unsubscribe();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately made no difference as I still get the same leak.